# If it possible to do behavior like setCanceledOnTouchOutside of dialog on Android

Tags: android

My layout xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_item_list"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messagelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If mybutton be clicked, messagelayout will be set to visible.
And while messagelayout is visible, I want to do a function such as setCanceledOnTouchOutside of dialog do.
While user touch screen beside messagelayout, it will set messagelayout to gone, and not do any other things.
If I don't want to use a dialog, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating another layout around the messageLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_item_list"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/messagelayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a wrapper around the message layout and have it cover all the area. Note the background color is transparent (#00000000 not #000000). Now set a onClickListener on the wrapper to catch all the clicks outside the messageLayout.

```
wrapper = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
wrapper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Hide the view
    }
});
```

This will catch all the clicks on the wrapper but unfortunately it will also catch the clicks on the messageLayout so you need to create a onClickListener on the messageLayout.

```
messageLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.messagelayout);
messageLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // If you do not need to anything here, just leave it blank but it has to be implemented.
    }
});
```

This will make your wrapper act like a dialog. To show/hide the messageLayout, you need to setVisibility on the wrapper instead of the messageLayout.